# bind message supplies 3 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0 [Node js, pg]

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, pg, node-postgres

I want to pass parameters to my pg query like this:

```
    await client.query("DO\n" +
    "$do$\n" +
    "DECLARE\n" +
    "  _db TEXT := $1;\n" +
    "  _user TEXT := $2;\n" +
    "  _password TEXT := $3;\n" +
    "BEGIN\n" +
    "  CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS dblink; -- enable extension \n" +
    "  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = _db) THEN\n" +
    "    RAISE NOTICE 'Database already exists';\n" +
    "  ELSE\n" +
    "    PERFORM dblink_connect('host=localhost user=' || _user || ' password=' || _password || ' dbname=' || current_database());\n" +
    "    PERFORM dblink_exec('CREATE DATABASE ' || _db);\n" +
    "  END IF;\n" +
    "END\n" +
    "$do$", [process.env.database, process.env.user, process.env.password]);
```

But I am getting `bind message supplies 3 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0`.
If I do not pass array of parameters, I get `there is no parameter $1` error.

So how can I pass parameters to my query?

Comment: Read this [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) and see what it says about parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Adrian. But to be honest I read this page few times and still don't understand the reason of that behavior. Postgre documention feels hard to understand...
Seems like something with dollar-sign. Maybe I need to go deeper with DO and dollar-quoting. I exchanged dollar-parameters with string interpolation and left it.

Comment: The issue is that `DO` does not take parameters. The `$*` are hidden inside the `DO`, your `[process.env.database, process.env.user, process.env.password]` does not have access them, hence the error message.  You would need something like a proper function(db, user, pwd) that you could pass the parameters into. Don't know `pg` that well, but could you build `db TEXT := $1;\n" ` as `db TEXT := process.env.database ;\n"`?

Comment: Oh, I see now, thank you very much for clarification. Well sort of, I've done it with the help of string interpolation like this: `_db TEXT := '${process.env.database}';`
You can write an answer that `DO` does not take parameters, and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: I would remiss if I did not mention that is important to make sure that values passed in this way should be properly validated before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overriding issue is the anonymous function `DO` does not accept parameters, per docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html). This means the parameters supplied, `[process.env.database, process.env.user, process.env.password]` have no place to go as the $* placeholders are buried inside the function.